# Javascript parsing JSON without jQuery

Tags: javascript, json

I'm following [this](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-php-to-hook-up-charts-to-mysql-data-base/) example from amCharts but I can't load JSON from PHP file, this what have I done:

```
AmCharts.loadJSON = function(url) {
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
         var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
     }
     request.open('GET', url, false);
     request.send();
     return eval(request.responseText);
};


AmCharts.ready(function() {
   var chartData = AmCharts.loadJSON('chart.php');
   console.debug(chartData);
 });
```

But I always get:

```
return eval(request.responseText);
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

I have googled but all solutions include jQuery, and it's recommended not to use eval.

Comment: `eval` is for evaluate a string as a script, its not for a `json object`.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` to parse JSON  - not `eval()` ...

Comment: console.log(request.responseText)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON) property, which is a part of the `window` object (unless you're using an old browser).

`JSON.parse(request.responseText);`

Here is a [shim](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) for IE7 and other old browsers.

To turn an object in to a JSON string, use `JSON.stringify({ foo: 1 });`

Do determine whether if you need the shim or not, you could simpy do

```
if(JSON){
    // safe to use the JSON object
}
```

Based on your comment, you have some invalid syntax:

```
[{ "date": "22/03/14", "value1": 15, "value2": 12.1 "value3": 15 "value4": 15 }]
```

Some properties are missing commas to separate them. It should look something like this:

```
[{ "date": "22/03/14", "value1": 15, "value2": 12.1, "value3": 15, "value4": 15}]
```

Note that what you posted is an array. There is no need to use `JSON.parse()`. The only valid thing as far as JSON is concerned here would be to stringify it to a JSON `string`. But I don't think that's what you're after here.

However, if it's the evauled string that you provided me with, then `eval()` should be replaced with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Yes, but even with JSON.parse i get in output Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: @BojanVidanovic Could you provide me with the string that you're trying to parse?

Comment: [{ "date": "22/03/14", "value1": 15, "value2": 12.1 "value3": 15 "value4": 15 }, {...}]

Comment: @BojanVidanovic as MamaWalter pointed out, the array contains invalid object literals. I'll update my answer

Comment: Yep, now it's working. Don't know how i missed that.
Thanks for help!

Comment: What does the window object belong to? Why don't you just write an example line of code?

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

is possibly due to wrong data in responseText varible.

I was also facing problem with eval() function. Then i debugged (use F12 key) and found that data in responseText is not correct.

After correcting data in responseText, eval() function is working fine for me.